# Cannot access pdf file from raw resources

Tags: android, pdf, resources

I created an android pdf reader using MuPdf library. My problem is when I change the uri to access the pdf file from the raw resources, **`Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource/[package]/" + R.raw.[pdf])`**, i get a `java.lang.RuntimeException` error. But when i change the uri to access the pdf file from the sd card,  **`Uri uri = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/[pdf]")`** , i will have no error and it reads and displays the pdf file successfully. My main goal is to read and display a pdf file from the resources, not from the sd card. Do you have any idea on how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Do this, it works for me :)

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://com.xxx.appname/raw/pdfId");
```

Comment: is the pdfId the name of the pdf file?

Comment: This does not work for me. It return java.lang.RuntimeException: unable to start activity

Answer (score 0):

Does not work for me!

```
String path="android.resource://com.artifex.mupdfdemo/raw/"
+ String.valueOf(R.raw.example_katalog);
```

results in

> 08-05 15:26:50.748: E/libmupdf(18977): Failed: Cannot open document: '/raw/2131034112'

Is there a working solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://"+getPackageName()+"/raw/" + "pdfname");
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri)));
...
} catch ...
```